# Respond a file and keep the file size using node js

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I need to create api to send a file and log the sent file size

I have tried the following code but `res.on('data'` is never called so it logs 0 but the file sent successfully

```
app.get('/get-the-file', (req, res) => {
   let size = 0
   res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      size += chunk.length
   })
   res.on('close', () => console.log(size))
   res.sendFile(filepath, {}, function (err) {})
})
```

I know there is `fs.stat` to read the file size but I think it would be more performant  because the `created stream` reads the file so we shouldn't need to read the file again to get the file size

Comment: So what's the error here? Kindly add the error message.

Comment: res.on('end') works?

Comment: the problem is `res.on('data'` never called so it always logs 0

Comment: Is it documented anywhere that `sendFile` emits `data` events on the response?  I don't see anything that states that.

Comment: `res.on('data', ...)` does not trigger when sending data - only when receiving data on a stream.  You can use the callback to `res.sendFile()` to know when the file send is complete.  There is no built-in way to know how many bytes were sent.

Comment: If you really wanted to count the total bytes written including headers, you could monkey patch `res.write()`.